# Moq raise event error - Parameter count mismatch

Tags: c#, events, mocking, vsto, moq

### Background

I have the following scenario:

- *MailItemProxy* class with a constructor with a single argument of type *MailItem* (MailItem is actually part of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace)
- Within the constructor of MailItemProxy, an event called **PropertyChange** (from the Outlook MailItem class) is registered:

```java
public MailItemProxy(MailItem mailItem)
{
    this.mailItem = mailItem;
    this.mailItem.PropertyChange += this.MailItem_PropertyChange;
}
```

My *MailItemProxy* class implements INotifyPropertyChanged so has its own **PropertyChanged** event (notice this is "PropertyChanged" rather than the Outlook MailItem's own "PropertyChange" tense).

The *MailItem_PropertyChange* event handler is as follows:

```
 private void MailItem_PropertyChange(string name)
 {
     if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
     {
         this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
     }
 }
```

### Intention

My intention here is to test when the MailItem PropertyChange event is fired, the class under test (MailItemProxy) has subscribed to that event correctly.

The test framework I am using is **Moq**.

**The issue I am getting is I receive a runtime error "Parameter count mismatch" on my Act line where I attempt to raise a PropertyChange event for the mailItemStub.** The PropertyChange event does just take in one parameter of type string as defined by delegate ItemEvents_10_PropertyChangeEventHandler(string Name) within the Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook namespace. If I remove the last two Arrange lines for mailItemProxy, the Act line then runs fine for some reason but I obviously need the proxy as this is the class I am testing.

Any ideas why I am receiving this error?

```
 [TestMethod]
 public void PropertyChanged_WhenMailItemPropertyChange_EventIsCalled()
 {
     // Arrange
     bool eventDispatched = false;
     var mailItemStub = new Mock<MailItem>();
     var mailItemProxy = new MailItemProxy(mailItemStub.Object);
     mailItemProxy.PropertyChanged += (sender, args) => { eventDispatched = true; };

     // Act
     mailItemStub.Raise(x => x.PropertyChange += (name) => { });

     // Assert
     Assert.IsTrue(eventDispatched);
 }
```

### Stack Trace

```
Test Name:  PropertyChanged_WhenMailItemPropertyChange_EventIsCalled
Test Outcome:   Failed
Test Duration:  0:00:00.2764026

Result Message: 
Test method UI.Office.UnitTests.MailItemProxyTest.PropertyChanged_WhenMailItemPropertyChange_EventIsCalled threw exception: 
System.Reflection.TargetParameterCountException: Parameter count mismatch.
Result StackTrace:  
at Moq.Mock`1.Raise(Action`1 eventExpression, Object[] args)
   at UI.Office.UnitTests.MailItemProxyTest.PropertyChanged_WhenMailItemPropertyChange_EventIsCalled()
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are [two overloads](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart#events) of `Mock.Raise` - you will either need to pass an `EventArgs`, or a `params object[]` as the second `args` parameter. In your case, you can use the latter and pass the `string name` of the property changed:

e.g.

```
 mailItemStub.Raise(x => x.PropertyChange += (name) => { }, "FooBar");
```

More [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016854/moq-mock-raise-should-raise-event-in-tested-unit-without-having-a-setup)

Answer (score 2):

**Update from someone who had a related issue**

I also had the issue that I couldn't really get the parameters right when raising an event, in my case with **one (relevant) parameter**.

This is the event that I want to reach within my production code.

```
private void ProcessDataSet(object sender, IMeasurementDataSet e)
{
    ...
}
```

I finally found two equivalent syntax for achieving this (it seems like the two separate parameters `this` and `measurementDataSet.Object` are converted into a `object[]` anyway):

```
_dataRecorder.Raise(mock => mock.DataSetAvailable += null, new object[] {this, measurementDataSet.Object });
_dataRecorder.Raise(mock => mock.DataSetAvailable += null, this, measurementDataSet.Object);
```

Once more I will also reference Moq's excellent [Quickstart Guide](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) - it really helps!

Answer (score 1):

I've just encountered this, and it was because I'd forgotten to inherit my custom event args class from `EventArgs`.