# Is it possible to stub a property in Moq and have an event raised on the set operation?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, events, properties, moq

I would like to stub a property on a mock object, and have an event fired whenever my test calls the setter for that property. Something like the following. Given:

```
public interface ISomething
{
    event Action FooChanged;
    int Foo { get; set; }
}
```

I would like to have a test like this (and of course this does not compile):

```
[Test]
public void HandleChangeInDependencyObject()
{
    var mock = new Mock<ISomething>();
    mock.SetupProperty(m => m.Foo).Raises(m => m.FooChanged += null);
    mock.Object.Foo = 5; // raises the FooChanged event on ISomething
    ...
}
```

Is this possible with Moq? All I could find was [a post from 2009](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/moqdisc/4m__O8WaaFI) on a Google Groups forum discussing it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
var mock = new Mock<ISomething>();
var raised = false;
// Setup the property to only raise an event it '5' is passed.  Instead of '5' you can
// specify It.IsAny<int>() to fire on any value, or It.Is<int>(expr) to fire on some
// range of values.
mock.SetupSet(m => m.Foo = 5).Raises(s => s.FooChanged += null);
mock.Object.FooChanged += () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("FooChanged fired");
        raised = true;
    };

Console.WriteLine("Setting Foo to 5...");
mock.Object.Foo = 5; // raises the FooChanged event on ISomething
Assert.That(raised, Is.True);

// Make sure the event is not raised if the set value is not in range
Console.WriteLine("Setting Foo to 6...");
raised = false;
mock.Object.Foo = 6; // No setup for '6'
Assert.That(raised, Is.False);
```

It's kind of counter-intuitive, but because event delegates cannot be invoked outside of the class that defines them the only way to reference them is to provide a valid but otherwise meaningless from which MoQ can extract the event reference, such as `s.FooChanged += null`.

(Credit to [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6016854/moq-mock-raise-should-raise-event-in-tested-unit-without-having-a-setup) for providing that critical piece of information.)

Comment: Thanks Jesse. I did think about doing it like this - but I wanted a real stubbed property in the mock because I needed to test that my unit-under-test set it correctly.

Comment: @BrianStewart Couldn't you just use `VerifySet` for that?

Comment: Yes, that is what I ended up doing. I guess the feature I saw in the Google Groups forum post was never implemented. Thanks.